# Why there is Internal server error , Unable to create node at /bin/searchServlet

Tags: java, ajax, aem

I'm trying to create a servlet in AEM which  uses the parameter from ajax  and sends the response from URL back to ajax request
but when I hit button its throws an internal server error along with unable to create a node at /bin/searchServlet.

response from URL is in json format

here is my servlet

```
package com.community.aem.core.servlets;
import org.osgi.framework.Constants;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Reference;

import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.HttpConstants;

import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.sling.jcr.api.SlingRepository;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.rmi.ServerException;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Servlet;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.*;


@Component(service=Servlet.class,
    property={
            Constants.SERVICE_DESCRIPTION + "=Simple Demo Servlet",
            "sling.servlet.methods=" + HttpConstants.METHOD_POST,
            "sling.servlet.paths="+ "/bin/searchServlet"
       })

public class slingdemo2 extends 
org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 2598426539166789515L;

private SlingRepository repository;

@Reference


public void bindRepository(SlingRepository repository){
    this.repository = repository;
}

public void unbindRepository(SlingRepository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
}



@Override
protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response)
throws ServerException, IOException {

    try
    {
                // Get the submitted form data that is sent from the
        String query = request.getParameter("query");
            
       //sending HTTP request and reading content using buffered reader

        HttpResponse response1 = httpClient.execute(getRequest);

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((response1.getEntity().getContent())));

        String output;

        String myJson = " ";
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            myJson = myJson + output;
        }

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonArray = gson.toJson(myJson);
        response.getWriter().write(jsonArray);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

and here is my ajax query

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('body').hide().fadeIn(1000);
        $('#submit').click(function() {
            var query= $('query').val() ;

            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',    
            url:'/bin/searchServlet',
            data:query,


            success: function(responseText){
            $('#result').val(responseText);


         }
     });
  });
    });
```

Comment: your servlet is not getting registered correctly, so instead of your code Sling Default Post servlet is getting called which is trying to create a node at that path(default post behavior), which is failing due to some reason(most probably permissions), so you get this error.

Comment: Related to your deleted question: Use [trim](https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) `'result1\r\nresult2\r\nresult3\r\n'.trim().split('\r\n');` instead. The comment you accepted will always remove the last position, no matter whether it is empty or not.

Comment: @Lain yeah I tried this as it is relevant thank you

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it would help if your Post(!) servlet would have code for post requests and not only for get requests.